# How can I locate the leak in my roof?

Tags: leak

My concrete flat roof is 2 years old.  Above the roof I have fixed terracotta tiles.  During heavy rains I find water leakages (dropping) inside my house in several places.  Water drain is perfect.  No water stagnation after rain stops. I couldn't find any cracks, holes in my roof.  Kindly suggest me how to find out the exact leakage point.  I would be ever thankful for your valuable suggestion.  I want to get rid of this problem.

Comment: pull up the tiles and see if the water proofing is damaged

Comment: If it's in several places, I'd say this isn't something you just want to patch. Sounds like an overall failure of the roofing system. Might come down to a full tear-off and redo, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the attic next time it rains. Look around for a leak above the places it leaks in the house. Additionally, sometimes leaks will "travel down" a rafter a bit before dripping down, so check your raters for water trails, and follow them!

Comment: I have never seen roof leak that did not travel quite a distance from where the leak was found.  Good luck!